# Android not trusting my Webserver which has a valid CA-Cert

Tags: android, https, httprequest

I am writing an Android app that should fetch some data from my webserver. Therefore I want to make a simple http get request from my app to the server. To test stuff I wrote a simple function in my Android app:

```
val updateUrl = URL("https://www.myserver.com/info")
fun getNewestVersion():String  {
        return updateURL.readText().trim()
    }
```

If I request that URL in my browser the browser does not complain about anything and just prints the plain version number text: `0.1.0`

If I do that request from the app it crashes and in the logcat logs I find:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
    Process: com.example.app, PID: 25510
        javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
        java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException:Trust anchor for certification path not found.
```

P.S.: The server has a valid SSL certificate signed by DigiCert RapidSSL Global TLS RSA4096 SHA256 2022 CA1 in case that helps

Comment: It is unclear how your app does a request. Is it irrelevant?

Comment: `a simple http get request` does not match https://...

Comment: Evidently your android device/version lacks the DigiCert Global Root CA available at https://cacerts.digicert.com/DigiCertGlobalRootCA.crt.pem. I'm not familiar with Android roots but I would expect that one to be there unless you're running an ancient version of Android. Have you tried testing this on other recent Android devices?

Comment: What Android version is installed on the phone you use for testing? Are you sure the certificate chain sent by your server is complete? Web browsers contain a list of intermediate certificates to bypass servers where intermediate certs are missing in the sent list (which is effectively a incorrect server configuration). Check your server e.g, using https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/

Comment: @blackapps if i try the same code just with ```https://www.google.com``` it works just fine

Comment: @Robert i am working with android version 12 on my test device. Also i tried the ssltest and the only thing it complains is "This server's certificate chain is incomplete. Grade capped to B." I am not sure tho how to fix that as i got my ssl certificate directly from strato (webhosting service)

Comment: "This server's certificate chain is incomplete" is exactly your problem. The server does not send all required certificates required by the client to validate the certificate chain. By definition a server should send all certificates except for the root CA certificate and your server is not configured correctly to do so.

Comment: @Robert I reinstalles all the SSL certificates on the webserver and now it seems to work fine. Maybe i had something in the old configuration that worked on breowsers but not inside my App. Thank you for the tip